# What is "n nought" in terms of "big O"?

Tags: performance, big-o, subset, algebra

I am wondering what the term "n not",  written n (subscript) 0, is. It is useful when proving big 0. I believe "n not" is usually determined after c.

I am currently trying to prove 2^n = O(N!). What would c and "n not" be in this case? Why?

Edit: I'd like to mention that I know what big O is on a high level. I understand what 2^n = O(N!) means and know why it's true. I'm just not very good at writing proofs about asymptotic notation.

Comment: it is the point after which the bounding function exceeds and grows faster than the bounded function.

Comment: n! grows faster than 2^n between 3 and 4. Which is it? 3 or 4?

Comment: between 3 and 4, 2^n grows 8 while n! grows 18

Comment: pick a value where n! exceeds 2^n, it doesn't hurt to pick an integer if possible. you can pick 10000 as well, it can be n0 too as long as after n0 there is no value that 2^n exceeds n!

Comment: I'm confused, you used the term "grows faster". That sounds an awful lot like the derivative. Now you're saying "exceeds" which sounds like "is larger". Which is it? They are two different things.

Comment: I changed my first comment. but, these are growth functions and what you are really doing is comparing growth rates. n0 and c are just methods to compare growth rates.

Comment: It's "n-nought". Please say what presentation of complexity are you drawing it & c from. What do you find in it re your question? Please google 'stackexchange homework'. What does your question have to do with [tag:relational-algebra]?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "presentation of complexity" or "What do you find in it re your question?". You're right. This has nothing to do with relational algebra.

Comment: It's not "n not", it's "n factorial". And n! will always outgrow 2^n because 2^n is 2*2*2*... while n! is 2*3*4*...